# Python:How find index of element in column with some condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my dataset

```
import pandas as pd
df={'A':['1@1','2,3','3,4',5]}
df=pd.DataFrame(df1)
df
A
0   1@1
1   2,3
2   3,4
3   5
```

I want to find index of data in column A which have `","`

I tried this code but it is not working

```
Index=[]
for i in df["A"]:
    if ("," in i):
        Index.append(df["A"][i].index)
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `index` and for test subtring use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
Index = df.index[df["A"].str.contains(',', na=False)].tolist()
print (Index)
[1, 2]
```

If need also not matched values save mask to variable and for non matched index values invert mask by `~`:

```
mask = df["A"].str.contains(',', na=False)
Index1 = df.index[mask].tolist()
print (Index1)
[1, 2]

Index2 = df.index[~mask].tolist()
print (Index2)
[0, 3]
```

Comment: i also wanted index which do not have ","

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is not with the for-loop, but with the definition of df. You have defined df to contain both integers and strings-- and are trying to obtain the commas based on string manipulation,which is throwing an error.
The proper definition of df would be --

```
df={'A':['1@1','2,3','3,4','5']}
```

After this, your code should work fine :)

## Edit:

In case you want to stick with the dictionary df, define the for loop as--

```
for i in df["A"]:
    i=str(i)
    if ("," in i):
        Index.append(df["A"][i].index)
    else:
        continue
```